# Complexity O(N) array and double for

Tags: c++

How can i get complexity O(N)? i, currently, have a complexity O(N^2), right?

```
    vector<int> coins;
    vector<int> div;

    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int b, m;

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        cin >> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            cin >> b;
            coins.push_back(b);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
code is here https://pastebin.com/bPG7D3W6

Comment: Hint: A loop inside a loop is generally *O(N^2)*. To get *O(N)* you need one loop and one loop only.

Comment: I'm not sure how "complexity" is a factor here. This code would have to be run many times for the inconsequential overhead to matter.

Comment: You have to read all the input one way or another, so the complexity doesn't matter there. It matters if there's too much data for you to store in your RAM (like many gigabytes).

Comment: Time complexity is for algorithms,.. and I can't see one here..

Comment: this is a little part of a domjudge exercise and if i upload this version i obtaine time-limit error. i'd like to upload a version with complexity O(N) (if possible) but I do not know how I can do it

Comment: You already have complexity O(N). Your N is based on `n*m`, which are independent artifacts. `n` just tells you how many `m` sets are coming.

Comment: To get a different complexity you need to give us a statement of the original problem.  What you have given us is your solution and hoped we can deduce the original question and then come up with a different solution.  This is too much of an ask.

Comment: You reduce time complexity by eliminating redundant work. If there is no redundant work, you've got the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 5):

That is not `O(N^2)` by the way. That is `O(N * M)`. Since you have two loops. One is from 0 to `N` and another nested loop from 0 to `M`. Maybe if you try to tell what you are trying to achieve, it would be easier to reformat the loops?

Currently I cannot see how to rework this loop with different complexity while maintaining functionality it has.

**Edit:**

@bitmask Made a great point in their answer. If you pre-allocate your vector, it will stop `push_back()`  from re-allocating vector a lot. Re-allocation is `O(N)`. The issue is that we do not have `M` constant, it varies on input of user. But you can perform *cute optimization* by allocating vector at least initially after you get `n`, to be size of `n`. The reason it is a cute optimization is because it will save you a bit of performance, but it won't be as significant that will impact your Big O.

```
vector<int> coins;
vector<int> div;

int n;
cin >> n;

int b, m;


coins.reserve(n);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm has a complexity of O(n + m<sub>0</sub> + ... + m<sub>n-1</sub>). In case all the m<sub>i</sub> are identical, this will result in O(n*m).

However, take a look at the complexity of the algorithm not in terms of its input but its output: You want to end up with a collection of c = `coins.size()`. As such it is *impossible* to have an agorithm that has complexity better than O(c).

Your algorithm runs in O(c) but seeing this is not trivial and depends on the specification of `std::vector`. A vector has amortised O(1) `push_back`, but non-amortised any given `push_back` can have complexity O(s) with s = vector.size() as it has to (potentially) allocate a new storage location of size 2*s and copy/move s objects. Still the amortisation means that you can hide all the copy/move overhead of `std::vector` inside the Big-O-notation as it is bound by C*c which is in O(c) for a constant C.

So, while you cannot improve the *complexity* of your algorithm, you can likely improve the *effective performance* of it. Namely by pre-allocating more buffer once you know any of the m<sub>i</sub>:

```
    cin >> m;
    coins.reserve(coins.size() + m);
```

This will reduce the number of allocations (**by far** the most expensive part of your program). To see the difference you cannot use Big-O analysis but have to **measure the performance your program**.

In case that your m<sub>i</sub> are likely to not vary greatly, you can even `reserve` n*m<sub>0</sub> once you read your first `m` value. This will likely significantly reduce the runtime further.

If you want to completely optimise the performance, read all the m<sub>i</sub> in advance so that you can reduce the number of vector allocations to exactly 1. But this will change the order in which you read input.

Comment: The issue with measuring the performance of his problem is user input factor. Because the time it will take to run will depend on how fast does user input data. Even if you stop timer before input and resume afterwards, that would be painful to perform.

Comment: @MichaelBykhovtsev No. You can very easily stuff all your input into a file and then pipe the file directly into the program: `./program < file.input` However, you are absolutely correct that in general `cin` and `cout` may wreak havoc on time measurements because they are comparably slow. But if the runtime of the program is negligible to `cin` overhead, that's probably the point where you can stop optimising the rest of the code and start finding a faster way to get data into your program.

Comment: Yeah you are right. You can test the algorithm with pre-defined variables in the file and pipe it. That would give you probably best time complexity(since we ignore time it takes for user to type each individual item). I agree that if they would reserve size of vector originally. Then `push_back` won't need to reallocate vector.